# RAID 0 installation instructions

Tags: raid, 16.04

I am looking for specific instructions for installing Ubuntu (clean install) on 2 identical hard drives in a RAID 0 configuration  (striped).  Have never found anything that describes how to do it...how to partition. ..how to install boot loader correctly etc

Comment: Setup your Raid 0, then you will see the 2 HDs as 1 volume with the combined space, then just install normally!

Comment: I need the detail on the part "Setup your Raid 0"; do I need to boot the live environment and do all manner of command line stuff to configure my drives as RAID 0?  I need very specific instructions on that part.

Comment: Well I asumed that you have a Raid-controller, or that your motherboard comes with one (almost standard now), You get into setup during booth by pressing Ctrl A or I or something else, it is displayed on the screen!

Comment: If you want a software solution, follow the instructions of FullCircle Magacine number 104 page 18 ( here is the link: http://fullcirclemagazine.org/issue-104/     to the publication - all about Ubuntu Linuxes - and derivatives etc...)
This is installing raid 0 on Mint -!!-- DON'T Worry It is build on Ubuntu and uses Ubuntu repositories - so for all practical purposes its the same